# Farseer 3.3 DebugViewXNA - Hooking it up

Tags: c#, xna, physics, game-physics, farseer

I have been trialling farseer 3.3 in XNA. For the life of me I cannot get DebugViewXNA to work.

I have a World object with a couple of bodies in there. The bodies are fixed to polygonal models, so I need the debugviewXNA class to draw these for me but cant find how to do it. I assume I need to pass it the vertices but cannot find how to access these from the World object nor do I understand which method to call exactly. One of the issues I find with farseer 3.3 is the support seems limited to "look at the examples" but they just dont seem to show the answers, google tells me I am not the only one feeling this way.

Any help from those more experienced would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to pass DebugViewXNA any vertices - it grabs that info from the Fixtures attached to the Bodies in the World. Here's how I got it working:

```
physicsWorld = new World(GRAVITY);
physicsDebug = new DebugViewXNA(physicsWorld);
physicsDebug.LoadContent(this.GraphicsDevice, this.Content);
physicsDebug.AppendFlags(DebugViewFlags.Shape);
physicsDebug.AppendFlags(DebugViewFlags.PolygonPoints);
```

And later on for drawing:

```
Matrix proj = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0f, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0f, 0f, 1f);
Matrix view = camera.GetViewMatrix(Vector2.One);
physicsDebug.RenderDebugData(ref proj, ref view);
```

Comment: Thanks Aranda thats the best example I have seen. Its only the camera object part that I dont get... I have it hooked up just passing the proj matrix and that outputs a tiny version in the corner.

Comment: Sorry an update, managed to develop my own camera class which I can use to generate a matrix for the view parameter. I cant seem to get it to size up correctly though which is the odd thing. The project I am testing it in is nothing fancy, just a 1280 x 720 environment with no zoom or movement needed.

Comment: That particular camera class was ripped from [here](http://www.david-gouveia.com/2d-camera-with-parallax-scrolling-in-xna/). Nothing special. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, ill implement it over my own later and see if it starts to look better :o)

Comment: On second thoughts, if all you need is a static world, a camera may be overkill. Note that the view matrix generated by this camera is the same view matrix passed to `SpriteBatch.Begin()`. You can possibly get away with just using `Matrix view = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(viewport.Width / 2.0f, viewport.Height / 2.0f, 0.0f));`, and not passing a matrix to `SpriteBatch.Begin()`. Have you studied how they do it in the Farseer samples? I think theirs is a similar setup with a static world.

Comment: Thanks, had a play and I can indeed see the debug view now, its not quite matching up in size to my sprite output. The interesting thing there is it seems my sprite positions / sizing dont match the simulation at all, I believe its to do with ConvertUnits class between sim and display, Ill have to get that fixed before anything else I think. :os

Comment: Sorted it! Very simple in the end. For the view side of the debug draw you just need to create a scale matrix equal to the pixel to meter ratio and pass that in, everything syncs up nicely now! Great in my little test project, lets have some fun moving over into the big boy.

Comment: Ah of course. The ol' world vs display scale issue. Glad it's sorted.

Comment: Yes its all looking very good now thanks Aranda. The scale issue came down to the fact that default scales are different in different "extras". in my case the provided farseer scale helper (ConvertUnit class) had a default scale of 100, where as the image to polygon helper had one of 77. Maybe I am being lazy but its normal to assume that things from the same source will work in harmony. Yeah I think I am just lazy and expect too much :o)